# Allow public access to java code in IBM Notes/XPages?

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-notes

I have an IBM Notes/XPages site, and I'm trying to allow access to one of the pages to anyone.  This particular xpage is fairly simple, but it does call some java code that is sitting under Code/Java in Designer.  I know about the Public Access setting for design elements, and I think I have checked it for the xpage itself and the form/view it uses.  It still doesn't execute the code on the page, and I'm wondering if it's because the java file doesn't have public access enabled.  If that might be the case, how does one go about enabling it?  I don't see a security tab for the java file.  Thanks!

(The reason for this, by the way, is so the xpage can be called by a scheduled agent.  That's made debugging this a bit tricky.)

Comment: Have you tried to set the *$PublicAccess* field of the Java note to "1"?

Comment: Can't the scheduled agent authenticate using a name/password?

Comment: Even XPage is Java code. So the problem can be in something else. Probably constructor fails when you access session/database. Look at sessionAsSigner.

Comment: Sven, that's exactly what I don't know how to do!  Other elements seem to have a security tab, but not the java file?

Comment: Richard, yes, that might be an option, but this seemed simpler, if it will work.

Comment: You could set the *$PublicAccess* field programmatically. But this is not your issue. I have tested it with a single XPage & Java class and public access only. It works without any problems.

Comment: Reid, share your code and give more details about what you do and what error you get.

Comment: Unfortunately, my code is on a computer on a different network, and I can't easily share it.  In any case, I should've stepped back a few steps; I can't even get a simple xpage marked as public access to load without getting a login prompt.  The page only has a button defined.  Sven, that is good to know, though, thank you!

Comment: Sorry, but I have to make this comment: did you enable read/ write public documents for Anonymous in the ACL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is somewhat invalid, it turns out.  Our server administrator disabled anonymous access, which I hadn't realized.  Thank you for your help on the matter, though.

Comment: Can you mark your question as answered, so it filters out of the unanswered view?

Comment: Done; sorry it took so long.